# Populating function inputs from lists

Tags: functions, procedural-programming

I have several lists containing variables, e.g. `list1={x1,x2,x3}, list2={y1,y2,y3}`, etc. I would like to define a function in those variables, i.e. `f[x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3]`. I have tried to use `Do` and `AppendTo` but this seems to reset `f` at every iteration. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
f@@(list1 ~Join~ list2)
```

Or, more generally, use `@@` to "open" the structure of `List`:

```
list1 = {x1, x2, x3}; list2 = {y1, y2, y3};
f @@ (list1~Join~list2)
```

> f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3]

For a list of lists:

```
listOflists = {list1, list2}
f @@ (Flatten@listOflists)
```

> f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3]

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @Bran it gives exactly what you asked for, `f[x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3]`...

Comment: @Bran I'm not understand. They are! Try it, pls.

Comment: @SlepeckyMamut How can I add more variables to the function not from a list? Like `f[z1,z2,x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3]`.

Comment: @Bran I generalized the answer, see above

Comment: @Bran `f[whatever, ##, whatever2]& @@ ...`